# Coloring Excel sheet cells using C# without Microsoft Office installed?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, exception

I wrote a program to do this but got an exception saying

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with   
CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}   
failed due to the following error: 80040154 
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

How do I resolve this exception and how can I use C# to color Excel sheet cells?

Below is the code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Drawing;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;

namespace Project32
{
    public class Class1
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Application excel = new Application();
            Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\mvmurthy\Downloads\IDBDeviceReport.rdlc");
            Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Is it about the exception you're getting or the title of your post?

Comment: Is there any solution to resolve this exception, else solution to title would be fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` namespace to "automate" Excel via COM then the respective Microsoft Office product has to be installed on the computer.

Otherwise you'll have to switch to some kind of third party library that enables you to read/write the files directly without depending on the Microsoft Office software.

Possible libraries to take into consideration:

- EPPlus
- OpenXML
- ClosedXML